# What are these little black bugs on my ivy?

Tags: bugs, english-ivy, parasites

I have noticed these bugs on new and tender branches of my ivy.

What are they, and how can I get rid of them? Neem oil doesn’t seem to be effective.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [aphids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphid) a soft bodied insect that comes in a variety of colors and suck plant juices.  They multiply quickly and some can fly.  I recommend cutting back the plant and spraying with soap and water.  This [question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/28861/499) is quite similar

For that plant and all aphid problems you can control by spraying dish soap and water at 5 ml/liter. Spray and leave on for a few minutes then rinse with water.

Repeat a total of three times to get the eggs as they hatch.